# Why am I seeing this error when trying to publish to shinyapps?

Tags: r, shiny, publish

I am trying to publish onto shiny apps a bar graph with the following data:

```
                  state mean_gain
1               Alabama  6.500000
2                Alaska  6.937931
3               Arizona  6.693750
4              Arkansas  7.306579
5            California  5.823729
6              Colorado  5.412308
7           Connecticut  6.422222
8              Delaware  8.725000
9  District of Columbia  3.700000
10              Florida  7.216176
11              Georgia  6.888750
12               Hawaii  6.166667
13                Idaho  7.000000
14             Illinois  7.932039
15              Indiana  7.683871
16                 Iowa  7.487000
17               Kansas  8.300000
18             Kentucky  7.926446
19            Louisiana  8.629231
20                Maine  7.288235
21             Maryland  7.876000
22        Massachusetts  6.553333
23             Michigan  7.922619
24            Minnesota  6.918182
25          Mississippi  6.993976
26             Missouri  7.239655
27              Montana  6.114035
28             Nebraska  6.906383
29               Nevada  7.694444
30        New Hampshire  7.700000
31           New Jersey  7.304545
32           New Mexico  7.179412
33             New York  7.547619
34       North Carolina  6.391089
35         North Dakota  5.940741
36                 Ohio  8.887640
37             Oklahoma  7.824359
38               Oregon  7.367568
39         Pennsylvania  7.082353
40         Rhode Island  7.683333
41       South Carolina  5.791489
42         South Dakota  5.277612
43            Tennessee  6.566667
44                Texas  7.543529
45                 Utah  7.353333
46              Vermont  6.920000
47             Virginia  6.595556
48           Washington  7.332500
49        West Virginia  6.937500
50            Wisconsin  7.234247
51              Wyoming  7.254167
```

The code I am using to publish into shinyapps is:

UI:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
checkboxGroupInput("select3",
                                             "Select States:",
                                            choices = unique(mobese1_df$state)),

                                uiOutput("bcheckbox"),

                                plotOutput("barPlot")
)
```

Server:

```
output$bcheckbox <- renderUI({
        choice <-  unique(mobese1_df[mobese1_df$state %in% input$select3])
        checkboxGroupInput("mcheckbox", " ", choices = choice)

    })

    output$barPlot<- renderPlot({
        bplot_data <-  mobese1_df %>% filter(state %in% input$select3)

        ggplot(bplot_data, aes(x = state, y = mean_gain)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
            ggtitle("Male Mean Obesity Increase by State 2001 - 2009") +
            xlab("State") + ylab("Percent Increase")
```

I am using a multi-checkbox filter to allow for selection of specific states. When I try publishing to shinyapps I am getting the error: Warning: Error in [.data.frame: undefined columns selected

Why is this happening? I have tried modifying the code every way I can think of.

Comment: `unique(mobese1_df[mobese1_df$state %in% input$select3,])`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all the packages you use are loaded

```r
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput("select3",
                     "Select States:",
                     choices = unique(mobese1_df$state)),

  uiOutput("bcheckbox"),

  plotOutput("barPlot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){


output$bcheckbox <- renderUI({
  choice <-  unique(mobese1_df[mobese1_df$state %in% input$select3])
  checkboxGroupInput("mcheckbox", " ", choices = choice)

})

output$barPlot<- renderPlot({
  bplot_data <-  mobese1_df %>% filter(state %in% input$select3)

  ggplot(bplot_data, aes(x = state, y = mean_gain)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
    ggtitle("Male Mean Obesity Increase by State 2001 - 2009") +
    xlab("State") + ylab("Percent Increase")})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This works fine for me with no errors, as you can see [here](https://mwangelekaluba.shinyapps.io/test/)